415 Unsupported Media Type in Java Spring Boot Application
I was trying to serialize and deserialize the bidirectional relationship in my database. I've used @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference to do just that...I have 2 tables (classes): Question and QuestionGroup. One questionGroup can have multiple questions and many questions can be a part of one questionGroup. When I tried sending a GET request (while annotating the proper fields with managed and back reference), the response I got back was serialized perfectly. Just the way I wanted. But when I tried sending POST request I got the error in the title:
415 Unsupported Media Type.
This is the full error message in my IDE:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (`java.util.List<com.ent.quiz.entity.Question>`) not compatible with managed type (com.ent.quiz.entity.Question)

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (`java.util.List<com.ent.quiz.entity.Question>`) not compatible with managed type (com.ent.quiz.entity.Question)

The 'perfect' response I get regardless of the POST request:
`{
    "id": 1,
    "question": "PITANJE1 GRUPA1",
    "question_order": 0,
    "questionGroup": {
        "id": 1,
        "group_name": "GRUPA1"
    }
}`

After I change the JsonManaged and BackReference to JsonIgnore I lose the questionGroup object. I tried using the @JsonIdentityInfo() but it also failed (Failed in a sense of the POST request works, but the serialization is ignoring the questionGroup).
How do i fix this so that I keep the desired response, but resolve the 415 Unsupported media type.
This is my code:
public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String question;
private Integer question_order;

@ManyToOne
@JsonManagedReference
private QuestionGroup questionGroup;
}

public class QuestionGroup {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String group_name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "questionGroup")
@JsonBackReference
private List<Question> questions;
}


When I reviewed my code, I noticed I didn't delete the @JsonManaged and @JsonBack reference, and implement both @JsonManaged-Back reference and @JsonIdentityInfo...Once I deleted managed and back reference, everything started working as expected.
